# Using a question mark in ruby methods

Tags: ruby, syntax, methods

Say I have class `Player` and I want a boolean method to check if a player is attacked:

```
class Player
  attr_accessor :name, :health, :attacked?

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @health = 100
    @attacked? = false
  end
end
```

I get a syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: (irb):14: syntax error, unexpected '='
@attacked? = false
            ^
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Removing the question mark from `attacked` fixes the problem, but I thought it would better follow convention to have `attacked?` in my code. It's not a big deal to forgo the question mark, but why are `zero?` and `nil?` conventions when`@variables?` and `def methods?=` are invalid?

Comment: `@attacked` is an instance variable, not a method. `@attacked = false`; ... `def attacked?; @attacked; end`

Comment: My guess would be that you can't have question mark as a part of variable name. That's for methods only. Also, I can't remember a single question-mark method with a setter. They're all getters.

Comment: That's a good point. They are all getters. Making a setter with a question mark creates the method "attacked?=", which is also invalid syntax. So my code would have an invalid variable name and an invalid method name as well.

Comment: I did a little further digging and just found this link to the [ruby forums](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/89770). I thought it was an interesting insight.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that if you comment out the line causing your error (`@attacked? = false`), you will still get an error relating to the question mark:

```
NameError: invalid attribute name `attacked?'
```

The problem is that `?` is not a valid character in a variable name. The first error (the `SyntaxError` that you’re seeing) is caused at parse time and caught immediately. The second error is caused when Ruby tries to evaluate the code and cannot create an instance variable with a name containing an invalid character.

A question mark *is* a valid character at the end of a *method* name though (actually it’s possible to have a method with a `?` anywhere in its name, but you can’t call such a method directly).

One way to achieve what you want is something like this:

```
class Player
  attr_accessor :name, :health, :attacked
  alias :attacked? :attacked

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @health = 100
    @attacked = false
  end
end
```

This leaves `attacked` without the question mark, but adds `attacked?` as an alias.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think about using an alias.

Answer (score 4):

I've run into the same problem before, and wished that I could make instance variables with a trailing question mark. It seems to be a corner case in Ruby's grammar. Check this out:

```
>> 1 ? 2 : 3
=> 2
>> 1?2:3
=> 2
>> @a = true
=> true
>> @a?1:2
=> 1
>> a = true
=> true
>> a ? 1 : 2
=> 1
>> a?1:2
SyntaxError: (irb):9: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
```

So the `?` symbol is overloaded in Ruby's grammar -- it is used for the ternary operator, *and* as part of valid identifiers for method names. This causes ambiguity in the last case, where Ruby's lexer seems to bite off the `a?` as a single token, which leaves it unable to parse the rest of the ternary operator properly. With instance variables, this can't happen.

Again, I agree that allowing question marks in instance variable names would be very useful, certainly more valuable than making some obscure uses of the ternary operator non-ambiguous.